# Salesforce marketing: path optimizer vs A/B testing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ab-testing, path-optimizer

Anyone can enlighten to elaborate the difference and when should use path optimizer against A/B testing vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the [Path Optimizer Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/path-optimizer-in-journey-builder/experiment-with-your-customer-journeys):

> Path Optimizer goes beyond [A/B testing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ab_testing.htm&type=5) (which uses two variables)—giving you the ability to test up to 10 paths in Journey Builder. What’s a path? It’s simply one sequence of events in a journey. Let’s take a look at what this looks like in Journey Builder.

So in essence, Path Optimizer allows up to a 10-way split between customers and A/B is 50-50.